# Running AMD Radeon HD 7870 XT Tahiti on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, amd-graphics, radeon

First of all, I'm new to the Linux world with graphical UIs and I only have some experience in using "headless" terminal only unix varieties.

I'm unsuccessfully trying to run an older intel i5-750 computer with an AMD Radeon HD 7870 XT Tahiti PCIE graphics card.

I installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with kernel

```
anni@APOLLON:~$ uname -a
Linux APOLLON 5.8.0-53-generic #60~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 6 09:52:46 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and on bootup of the computer, after seeing the ubuntu boot logo the screen just shows this weird pattern as shown in the photo below

[image: Weird garbled pattern on bootup]

I tested all of the video cards outputs, HDMI, DVI, DisplayPort 1, DisplayPort 2 with the same results.

I'm currently running ubuntu in recovery mode without any loaded video drivers without any other problems. The output of `lspci` is

```
anni@APOLLON:~$ lspci
...
07:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tahiti LE [Radeon HD 7870 XT]
...
```

The hardware is OK as it is running perfectly fine under Windows 10 so it must be a driver/configuration issue I cannot fathom.

Does anybody have any clues on what to do to get opengl/mesa grahpics acceleration working? I want to use the computer for some custom accelerated 3D visualization work.

Answer (score 0):

Try kernel parameters "nomodeset" or "radeon.modeset=0"

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Currently, your post looks like a comment rather than a complete answer. Please edit your post to include an explanation on _why_ you think this solves the OPs problem, and how you came to the conclusion what the OPs problem is.